# error: Call to a member function getColor() on string, en symfony5

Tags: symfony5

estoy intentando mandar por ajax una propiedad (color) de una entidad (producto). Si lo mando de esta forma me envia correctamente el id del producto:

```
public function source(Request $request): Response
    {        
        
        $producto=$request->request->get('color');
        
        if ($request->isXMLHttpRequest()) 
        {         
            return new JsonResponse($producto);
        }

    return new Response('This is not ajax!', 400);
    }
```

pero si intento mandar el color directamente de esta forma:

```
public function source(Request $request): Response
    {        
        
        $producto=$request->request->get('color');
        
        if ($request->isXMLHttpRequest()) 
        {         
            return new JsonResponse($producto->getColor());
        }

    return new Response('This is not ajax!', 400);
    }
```

me da el siguiente error: `Call to a member function getColor() on string` en esta linea de codigo: `return new JsonResponse($producto->getColor());` llevo un dia dandole vueltas y no se por que puede ser el error. Por cierto, indicar que la propiedad color es un string.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando estás haciendo:

```
$producto = $request->request->get('color');
```

Estás recuperando el valor de un parámetro POST llamado color, por lo que el valor de la variable `$producto` es el color, no la entidad `Producto`. Lo que estás devolviendo en el primer ejemplo no es el ID de producto, sino el valor de color. Para no confundirme, a esa variable la voy a llamar `$idColor`.

Si lo que quieres es obtener la entidad `Producto` a partir de la propiedad color debes ir a buscarla:

```
// La variable $doctrine la obtienes en los parámetros de entrada, ver en ejemplo completo más abajo
$producto = $doctrine->getRepository(Producto::class)->findOneBy(['color' => $idColor]);
```

Y ahí ya tendrías el objeto para obtener los datos que quieras.

Por poner un ejemplo, si lo que quieres es devolver el ID de producto sería:

```
public function source(Request $request, ManagerRegistry $doctrine): Response
{        
    
    $idColor = $request->request->get('color');

    $producto = $doctrine->getRepository(Producto::class)->findOneBy(['color' => $idColor]);
    
    if ($request->isXMLHttpRequest()) 
    {         
        return new JsonResponse($producto->getId());
    }

    return new Response('This is not ajax!', 400);
}
```

Y si lo que quieres devolver es el color sería devolver `$producto->getColor()`

Espero te pueda servir

Comment: gracias, me sirvio.

Comment: Perfecto! Me alegro 